# Touch Json CJsonScanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, touchjson

I am using Touch JSON lib, in Base SDK iOS 8 not able to get the `CDataScanner` extension class.

```
@interface CJSONScanner : CDataScanner
```

So that's why i am getting below crash, Any idea about this.

```
-[CJSONScanner userInfoForScanLocation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: found the solution, in iOS 8 need to add other linker flag "-all_load" into the Target setting and then it will compile CJSonScanner category.